# Why are the HTML classes of some major, complex sites written as seemingly meaningless strings of letters?

Tags: html, css

For example, I was just inspecting a page of Google's and saw a class written as `Yj Fg Ws IY fW Zf`. Is that to confound anybody who might want to understand how Google does what it does? If you're a developer for Google, how are you supposed to remember that, especially among all your other classes? Or what about anybody else who needs to make changes to that code in the future?

Is there a benefit to coding it this way?

Comment: I'm pretty certain google uses customized, automated minification, so developers are probably still using names like `super-awesome-form-field`, and the minifier would go through and replace that with `jQ` everywhere it's used in production.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to make the pages smaller, and thus faster to send to users, most major sites minify the files, especially the javascript and css files. This operation usually

- concatenates files to reduce the number of requests
- removes comments
- removes useless spaces and CR
- changes long variable names to shorter ones

One of the tools for doing this operation is provided by Google : [The Closure compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/). This is something easy to do and there is no reason to ignore it as soon as you start paying attention to the display speed or to your bandwidth.

Some developers might use it in order to protect a little their source codes but that's not the most usual reason.

Comment: That's interesting. Are you saying that a tool that minifies code will take a meaningful class like `Photos` and turn it into `FkdhY` or whatever automatically, but the source code the developer has still remains meaningful enough to work with on the back end?

Comment: It will more often turn "Photos" in "Er" but yes, that's the point : you keep your numerous sources files clear and full of comments and the minifier builds the version of your site that your users see. Personally I always deploy (automatically) two versions : the minified one and a not minified one for my tests. Note that in the future source maps will let us have only one (minified) version.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Re: that last bit, though ... source maps?

Comment: The effects of minifying *variable names* are so small that it's hardly worth it, particularly if you serve your content gzipped. I prefer readable names in production for debugging purposes. For Google, who are serving billions of websites per day, it may be a different story.

Comment: @Pumbaa80 I don't minify the variable names either (in javascript this last operation might bring its own pitfalls), but you don't need to debug the minified code. Even without source maps you can deploy side by side a minified application and a non minified one.

Answer (score 2):

It's done for smaller page sizes. When you serve the number of pages google do, shaving off a few bytes can have massive effects on the bandwidth you use.

Comment: and in turn, saves massive amounts of $$$$$ (literally millions)

Comment: Is there really a byte-saving difference between `Yj Fg Ws IY fW Zf` and, say, `Video Div` or something like that?

Comment: There is but the first example looks like it has 6 classes that have been 'minified' so it full it could be `className1 class2 anotherClass3 class4 fifthClass lastClass6`. You also have to remember that google are dealing with 100s of millions of page requests. Saving even 1 byte that many times over will add up.

Comment: @jeremygburton, yes, every character is a certain number of bytes, streaming less characters to the browser means less bytes transferred over the network, means less time to send a reply, means less time a server is busy with a single request, means less time a server is spent processing, means less heat generated by the CPU, means less electricity used to power the CPU and cooling units, means marginal cost savings that add up for technology companies.

Answer (score 0):

Save bytes and, as a result, save bandwidth? I think there are even programs for that which minify you source code, so as a developer you don't have to remember or even know the short names.

Answer (score 0):

This is done for two reasons. Usually to decrease the size of the website. All the sites codes are shortened and names are replaced my much shorter version e.g. `tellMeTheStuffFromThatServer(serviceABC, parameterABC);` is replaced by `a(b,c);`. Very rarely you see this practise too if someone want's to prevent his code from being read by visitors, allthough this is obviously not very effective.

Answer (score -2):

> So that u do not get a hang of their design from the names of the
>   classes. it might come back to hurt them. names of classes are not
>   just any damn thing, they are ideas. they are the framework.
>
> http://www.ebay.com/itm/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=111005600551
>
> How much more can u find out. u can instantly figure out that Ebay has
>   the same handler class for all its products and the handler is a Win
>   Handler which has 2 properties passed to it. Of course this is not the
>   exact stereotype of minifying as such but most websites would have
>   urlencoded that into a hash to avoid security threats as well as
>   design leaks..
>
> it would go something like 
>   http://www.ebay.com/itm/ws/_ylt=AouAU5ULtZy2c38mrOUIQJGuitIF;
>
> Put in meaningless stuff on the urls

Comment: As others have pointed out, eBay makes this change for minification purposes, not obfuscation purposes.

Comment: well u can check ebay, they dont have the latter URL. they have the former URL which does tell u a lot about the way eBay functions at least to Amazon. saving a few bits n bytes is not gonna get u anywhere in the days of cloud computing especially to corporations handling terabytes of data, IMHO hardware is way under utilised due to complex reasons and well i did agree with the right marked answer FYI. it is really a birds eye view while mine might be an aeroplane view.

Comment: You must have never worked in a large web corporation.  It is because they handle terabytes of data every day that saving "a few" (which is not the case, it is actually more in the range of 5-10%) bytes makes a huge difference.